# How can I run vcvars32.bat before code build in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, nmake

I want to compile my c++ codes with cl compiler. Therefore I started a "c++ makefile project" in eclipse. Then I wrote my make file. I must run vcvars32.bat firstly to run cl so I write that command in make file also bu it didn't work correctly. What should I do now? How can I run that command before building the code? By the way I am using nmake.

My make file is below:

```
OBJS =      helloWorld.o

TARGET =    helloWorld.exe

all:    $(TARGET)

helloWorld.exe: 
    **vcvars32.bat**
    cl helloWorld.cpp
    rm -f *.obj

clean:
    rm -f helloWorld.exe *.obj
```

Comment: can't you open a command line, run vcvars, then start eclipse from the same command line?

Comment: In that case, accept it as an answer for future reference (unless somebody else finds another way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command line, run vcvars32.bat, then start eclipse from the same command line.

The first two steps can be combined into one by going to `Start->Visual Studio xxx->Visual Studio Tools->VS command prompt` (exact naming depends on what you have installed)